# How to separate string coordinates into 2 lists: Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, list, tuples

Currently, I have a list of string tuple coordinates: latitude and longitude. I want to split this list of tuple coordinates into a latitude list and longitude list. How should I go about achieving that? I tried using the zip function and that isn't working. My current code is below.

```
latlon_ = [x[0] for x in latlon]
latlon_
```

This returns:

```
['(39.36356356, -76.53434457)',
 '(39.27426334, -76.54542274)',
 '(39.36461879, -76.56234642)',
 '(39.26932875, -76.60509948)',
 '(39.30447891, -76.61359834)',
 '(39.30411637, -76.61357519)',
 '(39.33636159, -76.6802207)',]
```

And, I would like to have 2 lists: longitude and latitude.

Comment: Can you share the original list?

Comment: [('(39.36356356, -76.53434457)',), ('(39.27426334, -76.54542274)',), ('(39.36461879, -76.56234642)',), ]

Answer (score 1):

```
source_list=['(39.36356356, -76.53434457)',
 '(39.27426334, -76.54542274)',
 '(39.36461879, -76.56234642)',
 '(39.26932875, -76.60509948)',
 '(39.30447891, -76.61359834)',
 '(39.30411637, -76.61357519)',
 '(39.33636159, -76.6802207)',]

latitude=[x.split(',')[0][1:] for x in source_list]
longitude=[x.split(',')[1][2:].replace(')','') for x in source_list]

print('latitude: ', latitude)
print('longitude:', longitude)
```

Output:

```
latitude:  ['39.36356356', '39.27426334', '39.36461879', '39.26932875', '39.30447891', '39.30411637', '39.33636159']
longitude: ['76.53434457', '76.54542274', '76.56234642', '76.60509948', '76.61359834', '76.61357519', '76.6802207']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first apply regex like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\d+[.]\d+")
latlon_ = [re.findall(pattern, tpl) for tpl in latlon_]
```

Then you have `latlon_` in a format you can work with and apply two more list comprehensions to extract longitude and latitude as floats:

```
long = [float(tpl[0]) for tpl in latlon_]
lat = [float(tpl[1]) for tpl in latlon_]
```

Comment: By some tweaking , you can have only a single list comprehension. ```aa = []
    bb = []
    latlon_ = [re.findall(pattern, tpl) for tpl in list_]
    [(aa.append(ll), bb.append(lt)) for ll, lt in latlon_]
    print(aa, bb)```

Answer (score 0):

```
latlon = [('(39.36356356, -76.53434457)',), ('(39.27426334, -76.54542274)',), ('(39.36461879, -76.56234642)',), ]
lat,lon = list(zip(*[eval(x[0]) for x in latlon]))
print(f'lat = {list(lat)}\nlon = {list(lon)}')
```

Prints:

```
lat = [39.36356356, 39.27426334, 39.36461879]
lon = [-76.53434457, -76.54542274, -76.56234642]
```